# centos lapack install error gfortran

Tags: installation, centos, scipy, lapack

I'm trying to install lapack and blas to install scipy and numpy.

But I can't compile lapack and blas.

I installed numpy without lapack and blas,

but scipy needs them.

When I tried to install lapack,

```
( cd INSTALL; make; ./testlsame; ./testslamch; ./testdlamch; \
    ./testsecond; ./testdsecnd; ./testieee; ./testversion )
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yjyoon/util/lapack_3.5.0/INSTALL'
gfortran  -O2 -frecursive -c lsame.f -o lsame.o
make[1]: gfortran: Command not found
make[1]: *** [lsame.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yjyoon/util/lapack_3.5.0/INSTALL'
/bin/sh: ./testlsame: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testslamch: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: ./testdlamch: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testsecond: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testdsecnd: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testieee: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: ./testversion: No such file or directory
make: *** [lapack_install] Error 127
```

above error message came.

I refered this site.
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn81/node13.html

so I type

```
cp ./make.inc.example make.inc
```

However, I don't know how to change Makefile.

Currently, I can't use yum.

So I need to install all the things from source.

If you know how to install, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

As Jaime told me,

I tried to compile BLAS using make
and the result was,

```
gfortran -O3 -c isamax.f -o isamax.o
make: gfortran: Command not found
make: *** [isamax.o] Error 127
```

In this case also, Error 127 came and

```
make : gfortran : Command not found
```

also showed.

It maybe problem of gfortran.

Now I'm using centos 5.9

And I can't use route account.

If I can sure that I can install program without affecting other people's account
even if I use route account,
maybe administrator allow me to use route account.

Comment: [openblas](http://www.openblas.net/) is fairly easy to compile (download, type `make`, wait) and includes everything you need to compile SciPy, you may want to try that route.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited question. please read this